# One time insert, multiple reads into SQLite Android app

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I know there are similar responses so I am going to make this very succinct. I am planning on developing an app which has 18 chapters and each chapter has 30 or 40 hymns. Now, Im planning on using an SQLite command, insert each hymn individually but after the insert, and after the APK file is generated, would the data on the database still be present? Or Does it need to inserted in on each install? What are my options?

Comment: ContentProvider may be a good option.

Comment: create your sqlite db beforehand (using any sqlite browser) and put in into your assets directory (it is just a single file). Into your app copy it from assets to app's database directory. Do some checks like that db is already available or not before copying.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sqlite database for you app...every time the app is installed.. new database will be created(of course the old one will be deleted).. and so the hymns will be inserted on each install..(but once you install.. on running your app wont create new database and insertions..).. hope this is clear..

Answer (score 0):

I am not Clear with your question..but if you r inserting data through your code..than on each installation your records would be inserted once..if you provide condition to do so for only once.

Answer (score 0):

You have to code the insertion of the hymns at the start/launch of the application, so that the database is ready for retrieval for the application. But the next time, the application is started, check whether your database exists and has the hyms (size of database), if yes, dont populate the database again, if no, populate it.  
I hope you want to read from a file/array and insert the records to the database.
Once you insert the records to the database, they are available for the reference until the application is uninstalled or the database is re-created. Sqlite database is a persistent storage.
 
  Now, Im planning on using an SQLite command, insert each hymn individually but after the insert, and after the APK file is generated, would the data on the database still be present? 
Yes it would be present. Once the application is installed, the code of database would be executed and the database would be created.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is use the XML parsing to show the Hymens in place of sqllite. Simply create the xml file with the hymen tag then get the tag and show the data on screen.